# Elasticsearch does not restart after updating config file for CORS

Tags: elasticsearch, cors

I have updates my Elasticsearch config file (Note:ES is 2.2) for making it CORS enabled.I had done the same for ES 1.4 and it worked fine but here its not working and ES does not restart .Below is the error and config file

Error :

```
root@XXX:/etc/elasticsearch# sudo service elasticsearch status -l
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2016-03-11 00:03:03 EST; 9min ago
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
  Process: 9710 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Des.pidfile=${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid -Des.default.path.home=${ES_HOME} -Des.default.path.logs=${LOG_DIR} -Des.default.path.data=${DATA_DIR} -Des.default.path.conf=${CONF_DIR} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 9707 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-systemd-pre-exec (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 9710 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 11 00:03:03 ubuntu-1gb-sfo1-01 elasticsearch[9710]: network.host: XX.XX.XX.XX
Mar 11 00:03:03 ubuntu-1gb-sfo1-01 elasticsearch[9710]: ^
Mar 11 00:03:03 ubuntu-1gb-sfo1-01 elasticsearch[9710]: expected <block end>, but found BlockMappingStart
Mar 11 00:03:03 ubuntu-1gb-sfo1-01 elasticsearch[9710]: in 'reader', line 67, column 3:
Mar 11 00:03:03 ubuntu-1gb-sfo1-01 elasticsearch[9710]: http.cors.enabled: true
Mar 11 00:03:03 ubuntu-1gb-sfo1-01 elasticsearch[9710]: ^
Mar 11 00:03:03 ubuntu-1gb-sfo1-01 elasticsearch[9710]: at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseBlockM...a:570)
Mar 11 00:03:03 ubuntu-1gb-sfo1-01 systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 11 00:03:03 ubuntu-1gb-sfo1-01 systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 11 00:03:03 ubuntu-1gb-sfo1-01 systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

My ES Config File is as below **(Updated YML After Below suggestions)**

```
# network.bind_host: 127.0.0.1
 http.publish_port: 9200
 http.port: 9200
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
# http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, see the documentation at:
# <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html>
#
 http.cors.enabled: true
 http.cors.enabled: true
 http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
```

Comment: You may want to make your indentation consistent (ie no extra spaces)

Comment: Make sure that all settings start at character 0 on each line, i.e. remove all space padding at the beginning of your lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every line must be indented exactly one space from the left. The line `http.cors.enabled: true` seems to be indented two spaces.

Comment: You should prefer no space at all and left aligned.

Comment: The default setup in the config file for Elasticsearch is one space indentation. Personally I think it's harder to mess up things by staying true to that. But it's true you could use no indentation at all.

Comment: I've always found it easier to have all my settings left-aligned and no spaces at all, especially since in that file there are many comments and it's not always evident to distinguish between 1 or 2 spaces among different sections. I think they added that extra space only for legibility purposes (i.e. so that the setting name is not directly appended to the `#` sign), but for no other reasons. In [ES 5.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/breaking_50_settings_changes.html#breaking_50_settings_changes), they will make sure to validate all settings before starting.

Comment: Also worth adding that YAML cares about indentation so no indentation at all is the safest way to a working configuration. [related issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/15374)

Comment: No luck I tried indenting but still same issue .Ill have posted my updated YML on question

Comment: The setting "network.publish_port" should probably be "network.publish_host".